# Is it possible to validate a scanner to check if it has a minimum (x) of the same specific values?

Tags: java, validation, netbeans, java.util.scanner

What I'm trying to do is validate a scanner so that if the input string doesn't have a minimum of two vowels it returns an error, however I'm not sure how to go about this and can't seem to find an answer elsewhere.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input alphabetical character string: ");
    while (!sc.hasNext("[aeiouAEIOU]+")) {
        System.out.println("Error, sequence requires a minimum of two vowels");
        sc.next();
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you testing to see if the entire input stream contains two or more vowels?  Or the next line?   Or the next token?   Also: do you need to *just* validate, or do you need to do something with the input / line / token after validating?

Comment: @StephenC Testing if the entire stream contains at least two vowels, and I just need to validate. Sorry for being vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a validate method each time they enter a value something like this.this one only checks for each vowel once though.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sInput = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input alphabetical character string: ");
    sInput = sc.next();
    if (!hasTwoVowels(sInput)) {
        System.out.println("Error, sequence requires a minimum of two vowels");
        sc.next();
    }
    sc.close();
  }
  public static boolean hasTwoVowels(String sInput){
    int iCount = 0;
    String vowel[] = new String[]{"a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"};
            for(int i =0; i < 10;i++) {
                if(sInput.contains(vowel[i])) {
                    iCount++;
                    if(iCount == 2) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
     }
  }
```

you could also split the string and count each letter then add up the vowels
you can easily do this by doing something like this.

arr[(int)'e' - (int)'a']++  that will increment arr[4] counting 1 e

you could also use a bufferedReader to count the vowels

Comment: This is an incorrect solution.  Read the OP's clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem where using a `Scanner` makes the problem harder.

The simple solution is to just read the stream one character at a time using a `BufferedReader` and count the characters that are vowels.

You *could* do it by configuring a `Scanner` to return "tokens" consisting of a single character and then counting the tokens that match a vowel.  But that's pointless ... IMO.